# Same Long string(Varchar(max)) get different hash value

Tags: sql, sql-server, hash

```
SELECT  HASHBYTES('SHA1',Script)
  FROM dbo.Sync 
 WHERE roadmapKeY = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848'
   AND VERSION = 18

SELECT  HASHBYTES('SHA1',Script)
  FROM dbo.Sync
 WHERE roadmapKeY = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848'
   AND VERSION = 17
```

Script is very long string, seems like 2047 character with varchar(max) value.
version 17 and version 18 is actually the same Script but get different hash value?
i think because hashfunction using reference or pointer for generate hash value that make different value regarding same string(because if varchar is bigger than 255, it will use external space)
any solution i can compare two string? i want to know two string is same or not?

```
SELECT Script
  FROM dbo.Sync
 WHERE roadmapKeY = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848'
   AND VERSION = 18
   AND Script = (
           SELECT Script
             FROM dbo.Sync
            WHERE  roadmapKeY = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848'
              AND VERSION = 17
       )
```

without hash is also do not work, maybe same reason

I will put big string here
version 17

```
DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = 'EA827DA5-D417-4E8E-9439-08032C339921' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '4AFCF04C-CE37-43C2-A2B4-0CE9B0D606A7' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '425E3BA9-5EEA-4800-A4A7-14104AA01BCE' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '754669BD-A955-4AD4-B385-17EDE2DECAAE' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'I' AND _fk_FormKey = '821F5377-FAC5-4D9F-8A65-1AC54015BBC6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '0FD298EE-4B77-4D81-9170-29E212EFC4D6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '82FE6FF9-144A-4F05-9379-323BF6CDC0E1' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '9792EC50-C5F3-4A76-B331-373180467451' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '9FDC4F6E-BEF1-41B4-A259-385E6A660B65' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '0DB2A723-1CBB-4EC7-8C59-4149E5FF9EE2' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '7ADADD59-3239-4C0A-92E5-52EEB9B508C7' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '5F508647-23F4-4967-AB69-67CFC8E8D514' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = '4A6B3BF7-7D11-4F63-8644-6A25D1142D15' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'K' AND _fk_FormKey = '69623C61-E884-40D8-95E9-6BC634E44420' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = 'A99D228C-5516-430B-87D1-6BE1550FE924' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'G' AND _fk_FormKey = '616F4A68-0286-4964-A24A-73CC3EC775E5' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'M' AND _fk_FormKey = 'D36B1F0F-7107-4DBC-97F0-76381E62DB27' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '81690817-DB4D-4418-BFAF-7702BA499F5C' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'H' AND _fk_FormKey = '4CAF4679-5A0B-4E6D-B4B3-7B690C055EA6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'G' AND _fk_FormKey = 'E66B6CCA-EF9B-4FE1-B98E-7B7CA6851ABC' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '0145AD1D-7321-4114-BE29-8807D0B3CC26' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '676150E3-1408-4DC0-BD28-894127DA2CCD' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '0DD47B03-114A-426F-89E5-8C4E5C41155F' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'L' AND _fk_FormKey = '0C2B3F72-C9B5-45BA-B81B-90E49A11795A' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '93D05DBC-1B59-41BB-90ED-98C00DE9F0C3' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = 'CD1423DC-8CE1-4923-B529-A48222060D21' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'H' AND _fk_FormKey = 'C2350B8C-04C5-452B-ADA7-B745DE0C24D6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'J' AND _fk_FormKey = '88878771-4A45-4936-8D32-B9530D5B8E09' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'I' AND _fk_FormKey = 'FE0928B3-3EC5-4D66-8450-BCC2586ADB61' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = 'ACAAE3F4-8AA8-46D1-9152-CB8D6C85A085' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'J' AND _fk_FormKey = 'FA60385C-DE0D-4C04-8937-D6B9950067BC' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '08CECB30-F8E3-4BBF-BDDE-D6D21065E161' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = '38FB9E32-9A2F-4E05-9563-D93EB7AE695D' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'K' AND _fk_FormKey = '8AAB9FE2-90A3-40E1-9641-DC15E297FD10' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'N' AND _fk_FormKey = '05E2566D-6BBD-4DB7-95E8-E594EE51D298' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '6DE99CAD-1A63-4382-B5A5-E6E48AC5DC26' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'L' AND _fk_FormKey = '8CFF8468-D12E-4DC9-831F-E958DEF2946D' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '334FA5CD-B972-4FE2-9B5F-F49F77764CB6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'N' AND _fk_FormKey = '419DB66D-6D69-4F89-8E9A-F95E92DC3B71' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'M' AND _fk_FormKey = '0CA63E19-A969-4CA0-83CD-FAAA0724D00F' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Mathematics-11',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'MA',SubjectName = 'Mathematics',Version = 18,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = '92406CB9-7F5B-4531-8C9F-5C0A4B4D6F50' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Reading-10',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'RE',SubjectName = 'English Language Arts',Version = 18,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = 'FC24DAED-B9D9-4BE3-AEC7-708EF29E513F' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Writing-10',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'WR',SubjectName = 'English Language Arts',Version = 18,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = '4F1615CC-BF52-46E1-8951-7B8913F2026C'
```

Version18：

```
DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = 'EA827DA5-D417-4E8E-9439-08032C339921' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '4AFCF04C-CE37-43C2-A2B4-0CE9B0D606A7' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '425E3BA9-5EEA-4800-A4A7-14104AA01BCE' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '754669BD-A955-4AD4-B385-17EDE2DECAAE' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'I' AND _fk_FormKey = '821F5377-FAC5-4D9F-8A65-1AC54015BBC6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '0FD298EE-4B77-4D81-9170-29E212EFC4D6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '82FE6FF9-144A-4F05-9379-323BF6CDC0E1' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '9792EC50-C5F3-4A76-B331-373180467451' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '9FDC4F6E-BEF1-41B4-A259-385E6A660B65' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '0DB2A723-1CBB-4EC7-8C59-4149E5FF9EE2' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '7ADADD59-3239-4C0A-92E5-52EEB9B508C7' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '5F508647-23F4-4967-AB69-67CFC8E8D514' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = '4A6B3BF7-7D11-4F63-8644-6A25D1142D15' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'K' AND _fk_FormKey = '69623C61-E884-40D8-95E9-6BC634E44420' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = 'A99D228C-5516-430B-87D1-6BE1550FE924' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'G' AND _fk_FormKey = '616F4A68-0286-4964-A24A-73CC3EC775E5' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'M' AND _fk_FormKey = 'D36B1F0F-7107-4DBC-97F0-76381E62DB27' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '81690817-DB4D-4418-BFAF-7702BA499F5C' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'H' AND _fk_FormKey = '4CAF4679-5A0B-4E6D-B4B3-7B690C055EA6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'G' AND _fk_FormKey = 'E66B6CCA-EF9B-4FE1-B98E-7B7CA6851ABC' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'F' AND _fk_FormKey = '0145AD1D-7321-4114-BE29-8807D0B3CC26' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = '676150E3-1408-4DC0-BD28-894127DA2CCD' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'E' AND _fk_FormKey = '0DD47B03-114A-426F-89E5-8C4E5C41155F' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'L' AND _fk_FormKey = '0C2B3F72-C9B5-45BA-B81B-90E49A11795A' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '93D05DBC-1B59-41BB-90ED-98C00DE9F0C3' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = 'CD1423DC-8CE1-4923-B529-A48222060D21' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'H' AND _fk_FormKey = 'C2350B8C-04C5-452B-ADA7-B745DE0C24D6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'J' AND _fk_FormKey = '88878771-4A45-4936-8D32-B9530D5B8E09' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'I' AND _fk_FormKey = 'FE0928B3-3EC5-4D66-8450-BCC2586ADB61' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'B' AND _fk_FormKey = 'ACAAE3F4-8AA8-46D1-9152-CB8D6C85A085' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'J' AND _fk_FormKey = 'FA60385C-DE0D-4C04-8937-D6B9950067BC' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '08CECB30-F8E3-4BBF-BDDE-D6D21065E161' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'D' AND _fk_FormKey = '38FB9E32-9A2F-4E05-9563-D93EB7AE695D' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'K' AND _fk_FormKey = '8AAB9FE2-90A3-40E1-9641-DC15E297FD10' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'N' AND _fk_FormKey = '05E2566D-6BBD-4DB7-95E8-E594EE51D298' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'C' AND _fk_FormKey = '6DE99CAD-1A63-4382-B5A5-E6E48AC5DC26' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'L' AND _fk_FormKey = '8CFF8468-D12E-4DC9-831F-E958DEF2946D' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'A' AND _fk_FormKey = '334FA5CD-B972-4FE2-9B5F-F49F77764CB6' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'N' AND _fk_FormKey = '419DB66D-6D69-4F89-8E9A-F95E92DC3B71' DELETE [Live].[SetofClientFormIDs] WHERE [clientFormID] = 'M' AND _fk_FormKey = '0CA63E19-A969-4CA0-83CD-FAAA0724D00F' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Mathematics-11',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'MA',SubjectName = 'Mathematics',Version = 17,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = '92406CB9-7F5B-4531-8C9F-5C0A4B4D6F50' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Reading-10',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'RE',SubjectName = 'English Language Arts',Version = 17,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = 'FC24DAED-B9D9-4BE3-AEC7-708EF29E513F' UPDATE [Live].[Test] SET _fk_RoadmapKey = 'CE9AD1B3-171D-4508-BB06-750A93EE7848',TestID = 'GRAD-Writing-10',ReportingInstrument = '1',SubjectCode = 'WR',SubjectName = 'English Language Arts',Version = 17,Updated = 'May 23 2013 10:59AM'WHERE TestKey = '4F1615CC-BF52-46E1-8951-7B8913F2026C'
```

just copy from database, is that different？

Answer (score 2):

This means the scripts are different. This could be for a number of reasons

- is any case different?
- trailing spaces (but that is discounted by the SQL you have
- non-printable characters in the script (eg Unix vs Windows line endings)
- things like hard space (`&nbsp;`) vs normal space (ASCII 160 vs ASCII 32)

You can compare with a varbinary conversion to see Hex differences

Comment: i can make sure it is samle......just copy two script in notepad document, and find one of them, i can find two

Answer (score 1):

Your strings are different. Just maybe in a non-obvious way like whitespace or unprintable chars. Print them out as binary: `convert(varbinary(max), mystring)`.

Comment: i can make sure it is samle......just copy two script in notepad document, and find one of them, i can find two

Comment: @hujintao That's a poor way to test. If one Notepad window contains "abc", and the other contains "abc ", then searching for "abc" will find a match in both Notepad windows.

Comment: @hujintao use an `UPDATE` statement to copy the string from one row to the other. You'll find that the hashes now agree. What evidence do you have that SQL Server has a bug here? I can't see any.

Comment: can you check my question update, i just copy two string from database

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What are those SQL statements that you posted? Try my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The two posted versions are definitely different. The difference is in the three UPDATE statements at the end of each of the script. The Version 18 script contains three `version = 18` entries, while the Version 17 one has `version = 17` entries at the same positions. (Well, no surprise there, if you asked me.)